# custom error message instead of the exception in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to throw an error icon in image if it failed to load image. Is there any way?
I have my image in size padding

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: _boxes(

              "https://nepaldrives.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/ktmnewservicecenter3.jpg",
              27.7147, 85.3355,"KTM Service Center"),
        )
```

I have used that image by calling in string
like this

```
 Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat,double long,String restaurantName) {
return  GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      _gotoLocation(lat,long);
    },
    child:Container(
          child: new FittedBox(
            child: Material(
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 14.0,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                shadowColor: Color(0xFF000000),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 180,
                      height: 200,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
```

And used image here

```
                        child: Image(
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          image: NetworkImage(_image),
                        ),
                      ),),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.
I have just executed your code on my phone and worked like a charm.
there's syntax error.

```
Widget _boxes(String _image, double lat,double long,String restaurantName) {
    return GestureDetector(
       onTap:(){
         _geoLocation(lat, long);
       },
       child: Container(
          child: new FittedBox(
              child: Material(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  elevation: 14.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                  shadowColor: Color(0xFF000000),
                  child: Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment:
                         MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                         children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                               width: 180,
                               height: 200,
                               child: ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius:
                                      new BorderRadius.circular(24.0),
                                          child: Image(
                                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                            image: NetworkImage(_imgage),
                                          ),
                                ),
                           ),
                       ]),
             ),
         ),
     ),
);
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible when you are using NetworkImage.